# Keras: how to determine at which iteration best val model was saved?

Tags: python, keras

Part of my training code looks like this:

```
    model_filepath = 'models/cnn_best.h5'
    datetime_str = ('{date:%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S}'.format(date=datetime.now()))
    callbacks = [
        ModelCheckpoint(model_filepath, monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, verbose=0),
        TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs_'+args.model_postfix+'/'+datetime_str,
                    histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True),
        CustomCallback(generator.batch_generator(is_train=True), generator.batch_generator(is_train=False),
                       args.model_postfix)
    ]

    history = model.fit_generator(
        generator=generator.batch_generator(is_train=True),
        epochs=config.N_EPOCHS,
        steps_per_epoch=100,
        validation_data=generator.batch_generator(is_train=False),
        validation_steps=10,
        verbose=1,
        shuffle=False,
        callbacks=callbacks)
```

`ModelCheckpoint` save model at best val score with `model_filepath` name, is it possible to add step/epoch also to model filename? i.e. maybe by deriving from `ModelCheckpoint`? or only method is to parse `history` for min val loss values and rename file? or don't use `model.fit_generator` but feed data from generator in a loop?(which looks bad option because in this case I will need to make wrapper above batch generator to make data loading multi process)

Answer (score 2):

If you put `verbose=1` in the checkpoint, you will see when it saves.

You can also create a quick `LambdaCallback` yourself:

```
monitor = 'val_loss'    
bestLoss = 1000000000
bestEpoch = 0

def saveFunction(epoch, logs):
    loss = logs[monitor]
    if loss < bestLoss:
        model.save(name + "_" + str(epoch))
        bestLoss = loss
        bestEpoch = epoch

saverCallback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end = saveFunction)
#and fit
```

If you like, you can also create a custom callback instead of a Lambda, in case you want to keep the vars inside it as properties.